# After the training phase, is it better to run neural networks on a GPU or CPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, efficiency

Sorry if this is the wrong forum for this question. My understanding was GPUs were more efficient for running neural nets, but someone recently suggested GPUs are only needed for the training phase. Once trained, it's actually more efficient to run them on CPUs.

Is this true?

Comment: I don't think questions at this level of implementation-dependence are on-topic, here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ok sorry! any suggestions on better forums?

Comment: Might be on-topic at [so]? But check their help centre first. (And sorry for not just saying that in the first place instead of waiting for you to ask.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby no problem! obviously you were just trying to filter off-topic questions and had only pure intentions. didn't post on SO because the likelihood of it being off-topic is probably 80%.

Comment: I don't know their scope perfectly, but [scicomp.SE] may have the expertise. That said, I think there is a CS question in there: which model of computation fits which aspect of working with neural networks better?

Comment: Anyway, define "better".

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE, Data Science.SE, and ComputationalSci.SE: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/14941/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Data Science.SE.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for the clarification! won't do this again. to be clear, however, there was no cross-posting on ComputationalSci.SE. that was suggested by someone but not done.

Comment: @Crashalot, Thanks for your note!  All sorted out now, so no worries.  (Sorry, I meant AI.SE but wrote the wrong thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Running trained artificial neural network is repeated performing of a matrix with vector multiplication and performing the same nonlinear function for each element of a vector. If both operations could be parallelised and vectorised, it is what is GPU well suited for. But it strongly depends on the size of given vectors and matrixes which depend on the size of the neural network. For small nets, CPU could be faster than GPU but it would not matter anyway. For huge nets, GPU would be probably much better suited if algorithm is written right.